# Why default handler is missing in this event dispatcher?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm working through a new Kivy book that was published just few months back.
There's this block of code which gives an example of how developer can
create his own custom events:

```
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
  1 
  2 
  3 class CustomEventDispatcher(EventDispatcher):
  4 
  5     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
  6         self.register_event_type('on_custom_event')
  7         super(CustomEventDispatcher, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  8 
  9     def my_task(self, value):
 10         self.dispatch('custom_event', value)
 11 
 12     def testEvent(self, *args):
 13         print('An event has been dispatched', args)
 14 
 15     def testCallbackEvent(value, *args):
 16         print('An event has been dispatched', args)
 17 
 18 ev = CustomEventDispatcher()
 19 ev.bind(on_test=testCallbackEvent)
 20 ev.do_something('test')
```

When I run this it errors out with: `Exception: Missing default handler <on_custom_event> in <CustomEventDispatcher>`

The book seems to be using Kivy 1.10.1 and I'm using 2.0

I've tried to install 1.10.1 but the installation fails on my machine. I don't wanna be
debugging the installation just for testing.

Has custom event handling changed from v1.10.1 ?

Any feedback much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement an event handler method, even if it doesn't do anything:

```
def on_custom_event(self, instance):
    pass
```